# Why do I need to use .str when I want to get an element of a list of strings in Python/Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

If I have a Dataframe and I use `.str.split()` on it, such as in
    `ebola_melt['str_split'] = ebola_melt.type_country.str.split("_")` 
, as I understand it, it returns a list of strings. Is that true?

In case it is true, why do I need to use `.str.get()` in order to get one element of the created list of strings, instead of just using `.get()` without the `.str`? Eg:Why does this not work,

```
ebola_melt['type'] = ebola_melt.str_split.get(0)
```

but this works:

```
ebola_melt['type'] = ebola_melt.str_split.str.get(0)
```

I thank you in advance for answers. Examples are from Datacamp.

Comment: `it returns a list of strings. Is that true?` Did you try it? If not, what's stopping you?

Comment: `Why does this not work,` `get` is not a first class function associated with the `pd.DataFrame` object, but it is an _str_ method, so it makes sense.

Comment: I think this all depends on pandas developer and the users' requirement in git, just like`melt` function ..

Comment: have you checked [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Pandas series can be of several types.  There are categories of methods that can be called on the varying types depending on the type.

For example

For a series of datetime objects, you can get at the `year`, `month`, or `day`.  You can even format it with `strftime`.

For categorical type series.  You can access the categories or factorized codes.

For strings you can `join`, `extract`, `cat`, etc...

However, it makes little sense to make datetime related methods available for string series or categorical related methods available for datetime series.  So instead, Pandas allows you to access the string related methods via an accessor that you see as `.str`.  After that are all the string related methods.  Same is true for `.dt` as the accessor to datetime and timedelta related methods and `.cat` for categorical related methods.

---

```
s = pd.Series('abc efg hij klm'.split())

s.str.get(1)

0    b
1    f
2    i
3    l
dtype: object
```

---

```
d = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2016-03-31', periods=4))

d.dt.daysinmonth

0    31
1    30
2    30
3    30
dtype: int64
```

---

```
c = pd.Series(pd.Categorical(list('abcd'), list('edcba'), True))

c.cat.codes

0    4
1    3
2    2
3    1
dtype: int8
```